# Further Filter Available Fields from Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

We are using the [CalendarView endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to retrieve a users appointments for a specific time period. While calling the endpoint we are passing $select=start,end,showAs to only retrieve the fields that we are interested in.

Our end client is concerned that even though we are filtering the results on our side we still have access to Calendars.Read and technically have access to read meeting subjects, etc. Is there any way in Office365 or the Graph API that our end client can apply more granular permissions to filter which fields we have access to?

Answer (score 1):

Today Microsoft Graph application permissions give your application full access to the entity they cover (all the properties)/the endpoint (all the payload).
There's is no way to restrict access to specific properties of an entity for a specific application.
You can always [suggest this idea on uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added a feature request.   https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38763799-allow-more-control-over-fields-returned-in-an-api